# Transaction rollback on connection failure or timeout

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, rollback

This question is asked by Navaneeth Adruguli on  [Link Of form](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2f55a9fe-b47f-4dfb-8aa6-0e25331a0989/transaction-rollback-on-connection-failure-or-timeout)

---

The question is:
In SQL server how transaction rollback will work? If i have a huge number of updates in a transaction and during update connection failure or connection timeout occurs then what will happen?Can sql server rollback in this conditions without connection to the sql server(in case of conection failure).If possible then how?

Comment: This question is already answered on this other forum.  Why post it here? Are you expecting a different answer?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server rollback the transaction if any error occurs in network of system. It can even automatically restore from crash if system crashes or shuts down in between.

Comment: thanks for your attention, but what will be happen if network losses from client computer.